# execute load into using sparksql

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have textfile val.txt in the hdfs i would like to use the SparkSQL. So i opened the spark-shell and exceute :

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE val(code string,description string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' STORED AS TextFile")
sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://localhost:9000/val.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE val")
```

The table was created but i got :

```
Failure:SemanticException[Error 10028]: Line 1:17 is  not legal 'hdfs://localhost:9000/val.txt:Move from ;hdfs//localhost:9000/val.txt to file:/user/hive/hive/warehouse/val is not valid .Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and"hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do  not.
```

Comment: what is `default.fs.name` in core-site.xml and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` (you might set it when you start shell)?

Comment: Try `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` to some hdfs location

Comment: for the default.fs.name hdfs://localhost:9000 and for the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir i choose a location in the hdfs  hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse. Thanks